# Imacros SAVEAS function on Windows Server

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros, palemoon

Hello users of Stackoverflow, I was just coding some imacros code and faced with unpleasant case.

Thing I'm trying to get worked: I'm trying to save !EXTRACT value to Datasource folder in imacros folder (Documents and Settings). I'm using Windos Server 2012 vps and Pale Moon browser which is similar to Firefox but much lighter. I have 8.8.2 iMacros version on Pale Moon.

Problem: I can't get it saved in Datasource file, nor in any path which is inside C:\

Code:

```
var irasymas = "CODE:";
irasymas += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n";
irasymas += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
irasymas += "SET !EXTRACT {{myvariable}}"+"\n";
irasymas += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\iMacros\Datasources FILE=somefile.csv" + "\n";
```

So I'm wondering that it might be some Windows Server settings related to writting in folders. Maybe permissions? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these options:

1st:

```
irasymas += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}} FILE=somefile.csv" + "\n";
```

2nd:

```
irasymas += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\iMacros\\Datasources FILE=somefile.csv" + "\n";
```

3rd: Remove your line with `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` and check up errors.

Comment: Thanks, as you noticed, it was a problem with correct path declaration.